# Dynamic list with fast button to change page in JQuery Mobile and Phonegap

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, android-emulator

Here is a simple description of what i'm trying to do in a mobile application. The end result is supposed to be a page with a list (of athletes) generated dynamically and linking to a page that shows the details of the clicked athlete. That is the part that is working, but the click is slow, so i tried to make fast button out of the button in the list.
Good to know : I use phonegap and test on an android emulator in Eclipse.
I have 2 html pages (in one file, as suggested best practice), the page with the list, and the page with the details

```
<div data-role="page" id="page_athletes_list"  data-theme="a">
  <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <h1>My app</h1>
  </div>

  <div id = "content_athletes_list" data-role="content">
    <h2>Athletes Finder</h2>
      <ul id="ul_athletes_list" data-role="listview" data-divider-theme="b" data-inset="true">
        <li data-role="list-divider" data-role="heading">Name, Firstname</li>
      </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

the details page:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page_athlete_details"  data-theme="a">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>My app</h1>
    </div>
    <div id = "content_athletes_details" data-role="content">
        <h2 id = "name_athlete_details"></h2>
        <img id = "img_athlete_details" src=""></img>
        <div id = "birthday_athlete_details"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the javascript i user to create the list dynamically without the fast button. This list needs to be created once on pagecreate.
Note: To change page, hardcoding the page link in the href of the anchor such as href="#mypage?index=1" causes problem in phonegap. Once the details is created the first time, it never shows any other data. To bypass this, I put the page link in a data-url attribute, which i retrieve and I use with the JQuery "$.mobile.changePage" function.

```
    /*
function create a list to the detail page with an index parameter. 
The index correspond to the the index of an array LIST_OF_ATHLETES where you can find the details information for all the athletes.
This array is used to fill the data in the details page.
*/
$('#page_athletes_list').live('pagecreate',function(){
    try {
        for (var i = 0; i < LIST_OF_ATHLETES.length; i ++){
                var athlete = LIST_OF_ATHLETES[i]; //LIST_OF_ATHLETES is an array that contains all the infos about the athletes. 
            $("#ul_athletes_list").append("<li data-theme='a'><a id='ul_athletes_list_item_" + i + "' data-url='#page_athlete_details?index=" + i + "' > " + athlete.lastname +", " + athlete.firstname + "</a></li>");     
        }
    }
    catch (error) { alert("page_athletes_list : " + error); }
});

    //change page on "touchend" event. Use the data-url attribute of the anchor.
    $("#content_athletes_list li a").live("touchend", function(){
    var dataUrl = $(this).attr("data-url");
    changePage(dataUrl);
});

function changePage(dataUrl) {
    var page = getParameterByName('#', dataUrl);

    $.mobile.changePage(page, {dataUrl: dataUrl});  
}

//get a parameter by name from a url (source).
function getParameterByName(name, source) {
    if(name == "#"){
        var indexStart=source.indexOf('#');
        var indexEnd = source.length-indexStart;
        var indexParam = source.indexOf("?");
        if(indexParam > indexStart){
            indexEnd = indexParam-indexStart;
        }
        return source.substring(indexStart, indexEnd);
    }
    else{
        var match = RegExp('[?&]' + name + '=([^&]*)').exec(source);
        return match && decodeURIComponent(match[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
    }
}
```

Now i tried many different things to include the google fast button in there but nothing seemed to work.
You can find the code for fast button here : https://github.com/h5bp/mobile-boilerplate/blob/master/js/helper.js

The first thing i tried was to add a new fast button after the creation the anchor.
example :

```
$("#ul_athletes_list").append("<li data-theme='a'><a id='ul_athletes_list_item_" + i + "'  > " + athlete.lastname +", " + athlete.firstname + "</a></li>"); 
new MBP.fastButton(document.getElementById('ul_athletes_list_item_' + i), function(){changePage("#page_athlete_details?index=" + i )});
```

When i do this the document.getElementById doesn't find the anchor 'ul_athletes_list_item_' +i.
Probably because it isn't in the dom yet.
I changed strategy and tried to list element via javascript then create the button the newly created element.

```
$('#page_athletes_list').live('pagecreate',function(){
    try {
        for (var i = 0; i < LIST_OF_ATHLETES.length; i ++){
            var athlete = LIST_OF_ATHLETES[i];
            var page = "#page_athlete_details?index=" + i ;
            var list = document.getElementById("ul_athletes_list");
            var li = document.createElement("li");
            var anchor = document.createElement("a");
            anchor.innerHTML = athlete.lastname +", " + athlete.firstname;
            new MBP.fastButton(anchor, function(){changePage(page)}); //the fastbutton on the current element of the list
            li.appendChild(anchor);
            list.appendChild(li);       
        }
    }
    catch (error) { alert("page_athletes_list : " + error); }
});
```

This doesn't work. All the button redirects to "#page_athlete_details" with the index value equals to the last element of the array LIST_OF_ATHLETES. If I have 6 elements in my array, all the buttons will have redirect to url "#page_athlete_details.index=5". Instead of having first button with index=0, second button with index=1, etc...

So finally, the question, if anyone knows why this doesn't work or has an alternate solution, i would be greatful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MBP.fastButton is asynchronous - the callback function with `changePage(page)` doesn't actually run until after the loop is finished, at which point i is set to 5.

To reliably use a callback in a loop, you need a new scope with each iteration. I usually make the loop itself asynchronous by replacing it with a recursive function, but in this case a self executing function in the body of the loop is probably a better fit.

```
(function(page_local) {
    new MBP.fastButton(anchor, function(){changePage(page_local)}); 
})(page_global);
```

I renamed the variable to clarify which one is being used, but in this case it shouldn't matter if the same name is used in different scopes.

Comment: Thanks it's working. Learned more about asynchronous function at the same time.